# How to use Github Release Version Number in Github Action

Tags: github, version, pipeline, github-actions

I have created a Github repo that has got an action to build the npm package and publish it to npmjs.com. The trigger for my action is the creation of a new release in Github. When creating the new release, Github is asking me for a version number. I would love to use this version number in the Action and provide it to the yarn publish command.

My ci-file looks like this (i stripped some parts that are not important here):

```
name: Deploy npm package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish-npm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn build
      - run: yarn publish --new-version ${...}
        env:a
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

Is there an environmental variable that contains the version number from the release?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It should be `${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}`. The structure of a release can be found here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release

I'd also suggest to use

```
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
```

instead of created to avoid putting something to npm for draft releases.
See: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#release-event-release

**Hint:**

To debug the event you can use:

```
jobs:
  debug:
    name: Debug
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump env
        run: env | sort
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

Comment: It looks pretty sophisticated. I will check it tomorrow and mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: Isn't `published` also fired for drafts and only `created` only used for non-draft releases?

Comment: Thank you @scthi, dumping the GitHub context helped!

Answer (score 18):

You can get tag version using `${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}`.

Comment: Here's the reference with all information you can get from the webhooks that trigger GH Actions: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push