# How to get Python package version in Github Action?

Tags: python, github-actions

I have [a Github Action](https://github.com/polm/fugashi/blob/master/.github/workflows/windows.yml) that builds Windows wheels. At the end of the build it installs the wheels to make sure everything's OK, but right now the version is hard coded in the filename. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518658/how-to-use-github-release-version-number-in-github-action) that deals with releases, but I'd like to run this on every push to master to check that things are OK.

Right now there's a line in my action looks like this:

```
pip install "fugashi-0.1.9rc1-cp${{ matrix.py-short }}-cp${{ matrix.py-short2 }}-win_amd64.whl"
```

I don't want to have to update the action every time the version changes, so I would like the line to look like this:

```
pip install "fugashi-$VERSION-cp${{ matrix.py-short }}-cp${{ matrix.py-short2 }}-win_amd64.whl"
```

But I do not know how to get the version into the environment of the github action.

Is there some way I can get the version number from setup.py in an environment variable for the job?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the version is defined in setup.py? Are you looking to change the version in `setup.py`?

Comment: It's not a problem that the version number is in setup.py, the problem is the version number isn't in the environment. I edited the question to clarify what I want to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ended up being much simpler than I thought. You can just get the version from setup.py itself and use that.

```
VERSION=$(python setup.py --version)
pip install "dist/fugashi-$VERSION-cp${{ matrix.py-short }}-cp${{ matrix.py-short2 }}-win_amd64.whl"
```

Trying to change the Github Action environment was a distraction.